# Automated Individualised (personalised) emails based on survey outcome?

Tags: excel, email

I am distributing a survey to students, and this survey has multiple-choice questions. What I want is, when the answers are revealed depending on the answers, I want the pc to send automatically an individualised email that tells the student what to do.

Is there a way of doing this?

Like for example, if I asked a student these two questions:

> 1. Have you ever studied trigonometric functions
>
> a) Yes, I am pretty good in them
> b) Yes, but I need some resources to
> review
> c) No, never bothered.
>
> 2. Have you ever studied Optimization Techniques?
>
> a) Yes, I am pretty good in them
> b) Yes, but I need some resources to
> review
> c) No

If a student answers, was 1) a, and 2) c

Then an email is generated.

> "Thank you so much for completing the survey, based on your result, and it seems that you need to study Optimization techniques. The resources that are required are: bla bla bla."

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a resource to have people write your programs for you. It's a resource for developers to receive help when they run into specific problems when trying to implement a solution. Otherwise you should google a tutorial on how to accomplish your task. You tagged your post with Excel for some reason, so [here's](https://www.encodedna.com/excel/how-to-parse-outlook-emails-and-show-in-excel-worksheet-using-vba.htm) a tutorial on reading an email using VBA, and [here's](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail4.htm) how to send one. Both tutorials use Outlook.

Comment: @tom I am not asking you to write a code. I am asking if something like this exists. I haven’t seen anything like this online and I was wondering if this exist or not.

Comment: @rsc05 it depends on the format of the responses that you get. Are you just logging the survey responses into a spreadsheet? If yes, then this definitely can be done without too much involvement

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 yes, but how can I communicate with excel to write for each student an individualise email to make him or her aware of resources ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like this using many different mailinglist software packages and cloud services.  This question is a bit too general and open-ended for a specific answer, so here's a general one.

For example, the open-source Sympa mailing list server ( www.sympa.org ) is capable of having metadata (survey results) for individual list members, and then using its built-in mailmerge features to construct personalised messages that use the metadata to enable or disable sections.  However, it would mean installing a mailing list server which may be a bit of overkill if this is a one-off.  You can also do this sort of thing with MailChimp (though I am loathe to recommend them).

Of course, whichever solution you use, you will need to upload the survey results and email addresses to your mailmerge database.

The exact details of how to do this are left as an exercise for the reader, though this should provide some ideas :)